# How do I implement eps2pgf command line tool?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I use MiKTeX 2.8 on a Windows 7 (64bit) machine and I would like to use the `eps2pgf` interpreter. I have no idea how to proceed after downloading [`eps2pgf.zip`](http://sourceforge.net/projects/eps2pgf/files/latest/download). [image: list of errors]
[state.eps file](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKdee.png)

Comment: Have you tried to unpack it(maybe you need a zip tool - google it). Often there would be a README file or some other text file describing how to install and use the tool.

Answer (score 2):

`eps2pgf` appears to be a java application.  You need to have java, version at least 1.5, installed, in order to run it.  There seems to be a complete manual contained in the zip file.  Unzip the file, and in the `doc` subdirectory,read the file `eps2pgf_manual.pgf`.

It seems that the program is rather picky, and will not work with number of postscript files that otherwise behave perfectly well.  A workaround that I found is to convert the files with [purifyeps](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/purifyeps) first.  The `eps2pgf` seems to work fine with the "purified" files.  The `purifyeps` program is supposedly not included with MikTeX, though.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I did look over the manual you referenced before my original post and I do have the latest version of java. I am trying to execute the code using a command line on simple eps file (outline of a state in the US). The program generates a pgf file that does not draw anything.

Comment: Is there an error message of any sort when you run the program?

Comment: Thanks again for responding. I attached the errors I get to my original post.

Comment: It seems that `eps2pgf` cannot handle your `eps` file.  You can try to submit a bug report at http://sourceforge.net/tracker/?group_id=188852&atid=926973 including your file, the author may be able to fix that.  The program seems to be rather picky, though, out of about 15 files that I randomly found on my disk, it could handle only 4 of them. The rest gave errors same or similar to what you got.

Comment: Thanks! I suspect that eps2pgf had difficulty handling some files. I actually tried three and none worked.

Comment: I have found that passing it through `eps2eps` utility can also help as well.